# Rails: jQuery adding and removing fields in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add new fields in a form using jQuery.

This is new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @hour do |f| %>
  <div id="hourSet">
    <%= render partial: "hours_form" %>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:;" id="addNewHour">Add Hours</a>

  <div class="hide" id="new_hours_form">
    <%= render partial: "hours_form", locals: {hour: false} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

js file

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#addNewHour").on "click", ->
    $("#hourSet").append $("#new_hours_form").html()

  $("#removeNewHour").on "click", ->
    $("#hourSet").remove()
```

_hours_form.html.erb

```
<div class="hoursForm">
  <%= label_tag 'day' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'day[]' %>
  <%= label_tag 'open_time' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'open_time[]' %>
  <%= label_tag 'close_time' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'close_time[]' %>  

  <a href="#" id="removeNewHour">X</a>
</div>
```

When I'm trying to populate the fields, only the first X works, and it deletes all the fields. I like to only delete 1 at a time. Whats a best method to add unique ids and get those ids for easy removal?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have id field inside @hour object. If so i think u can use it to make div unique. ex: <div id="hourset<%= @hour.id%>">... </div>

Comment: @Dave would `@hour.id` only work if there was an id (for existing data?). Since I'm adding new data, there wouldn't be `@hour.id` that exists yet?

Comment: you are correct. how about using a javascript counter variable appended to id with underscore between them. on each click of #addNewHour increment counter variable and decrement counter on click of #removeNewHour. while retrieving we can split using underscore and get id of div to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L8Zx/#run)
you can refer and alter your code accordingly. I have used closest method of jquery for removel purpose. If this is useful then i don't think there is necessity for unique ids.

```
$(this).closest('.hoursForm').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, this one helped me lots!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first "X" delete link works is because your javascript attaches the click events at document ready. And at that moment, you just have your first "X" in the screen.

To fix that you can attach events using `delegate` instead of `on`. And you shouldn't need to assign `id` to each X links. Your JS could look like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  // Keep the same here
  $("#addNewHour").on "click", ->
    $("#hourSet").append $("#new_hours_form").html()

  // This code below handles the click on the delete link ("X")
  $('.hoursForm').delegate "a", "click", ->
    $(this).parent().remove()
```

Hope that works.

Comment: I thought this would work, but its not doing anything on the new fields (when I click on `Add Hours`), however, it works on the first `hoursForm` container when I click on the X (from the first `hoursForm` container)

Answer (score 0):

try change js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addNewHour").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#hourSet").append($("#new_hours_form").html());
  });
});

var removeHours = function(elem){
       $(elem).parent().remove();
};
```

and change html in #removeNewHour -> add attribute `onclick="removeHours(this); return false;"`

Comment: is there a way to create a unique id with jquery? Because the id `removeNewHour` only works on the first link when I continue to add new hours.

Comment: you can e.g. set timestamp as id

$("#hourSet").append($($("#new_hours_form").html()).attr('id',new Date().getTime()));

Comment: @dbucki I'm afraid only the last child will be removed according to your code.